# Rails multiple create/update forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Due to business logic, I want certain resources in my Rails app to be able to be created and updated from various forms.  So for example, I have a resource `Business`, and depending on whether the user has just signed up or has been on the site for a while, a Business can be created from `/account_setup` (first time user) or `/businesses/new` (existing users).

I want to have both forms post to the same `:create` method and I want the method to be smart enough to figure out which page did the posting so it can render that page if it fails a validation.  Just for clarity:

`GET /account_setup` => `POST /businesses` => `businesses#create` => {fail} => `render 'account_setup'`

`GET /businesses_new` => `POST /businesses` => `businesses#create` => {fail} => `render 'new'`

Since both are looking to create a Business, it's pointless to have two separate controller methods, and I'm assuming there's a Rails-y way to solve this.  What's a good way to detect which of my two forms did the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use request.original_fullpath in businesses#create or embed values specific to the pages(controllers) that show the forms using hidden_field.

Answer (score 0):

You can put hidden fields in the form which will store the type of the form. Keep in mind, if it's a new user then you will have to create the user before creating business assuming the models are associated.